Алгоритм генерации промежуточного изображения
Нужен алгоритм, который сможет по двум изображениям сделать промежуточное:
Есть 2 почти одинаковых изображения, у которых есть различия в некоторой детали, нужен алгоритм, который сгенерирует промежуточное по этим двум, которое будет являться ~средним между ними.
Например: изображение1 это картинка с котом, изображение2 это та же картинка, но у кота длиннее хвост. Алгоритм генерирует картинку, где хвост немного длиннее чем на первой картинке, но короче чем на второй.
Алгоритм полного преобразования одного изображения в другое тоже подойдет, если будет возможность сохранить промежуточные результаты.

это нереально сложная штука, это набор из математических алгоритмов, весьма не тривиальных, причём - они работают на граничных условиях, т.е. если "по простому" - не универсальны, т.е. не применимы к любым картинкам; а вообще в это лучше не лезть, если обозначить грандиозность проблем по шкале грандиозности от 1 до 10 - это где то ближе к 11; а если затачивать сие на перфоманс - это уже ближе к 15

особенно жёстко это проявляется в генерации так называемого "межкадра", это когда есть поток на 24 фпса, а нужно нагенерировать промежуточных изображений, т.е. вместо 24 фпсов сделать например 48 фпсов - в этом можно утонуть навсегда

@InterceptorTSK я когда-то давно в университете видел нечто подобное тому, что мне нужно, как я думаю. Название алгоритма за ненадобностью забыл, а вот и зря. Там велосипед превращали кружку, кажется.
В моем случае нет потоков изображений, просто две статичные картинки, к тому же очень похожие друг на друга с отличиями в одной-двух деталях, которые как правило касаются изменений размера этих деталей. Тот же пример с котиком всё хорошо описывает. Всегда почему-то казалось, что такие алгоритмы тривиальны

Если вдруг вы знаете готовые платные решения либо в какую сторону стоит копать, сообщите пожалуйста

тогда вы про банальный [впрочем не такой уж банальный] морфинг пишете; https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Морфинг

суть: морфинг это такая штука, которая действительно позволит вам из котикаА и котикаБ - получить промежуточного котика, но морфинг работает на условных реперных точках, а вот если без них - тогда их нужно как то вычислить - и вот с этим беда, всё грандиозно усложняется; а в универе вы видели именно морфинг, на точках
